# Querydsl: How do I sort by a date without the time fraction?

Tags: date, time, querydsl

My starting point was:

```
Predicate predicate = (...);
OrderSpecifier<?>[] orderSpecifiers = createOrderSpecifiers();
entityRepository.findAll(predicate, orderSpecifiers);
```

+

```
private OrderSpecifier<?>[] createOrderSpecifiers() {

    final OrderSpecifier<?>[] orderSpecifiers = new OrderSpecifier<?>[2];
    /***********************************************************/
    /***********************************************************/
    /***********************************************************/
    orderSpecifiers[0] = QEntity.entity.dateToBeSortedBy.desc();
    /***********************************************************/
    /***********************************************************/
    /***********************************************************/
    orderSpecifiers[1] = QEntity.entity.entity2.id.asc();       

    return orderSpecifiers;
}
```

and I wanted to sort by dateToBeSortedBy ignoring the time fraction of dateToBeSortedBy.

I will post my solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private OrderSpecifier<?>[] createOrderSpecifiers() {

    final OrderSpecifier<?>[] orderSpecifiers = new OrderSpecifier<?>[4];
    /***********************************************************************/
    /***********************************************************************/
    /***********************************************************************/
    orderSpecifiers[0] = QEntity.entity.dateToBeSortedBy.year().desc();
    orderSpecifiers[1] = QEntity.entity.dateToBeSortedBy.month().desc();
    orderSpecifiers[2] = QEntity.entity.dateToBeSortedBy.dayOfMonth().desc();
    /***********************************************************************/
    /***********************************************************************/
    /***********************************************************************/
    orderSpecifiers[3] = QEntity.entity.entity2.id.asc();       

    return orderSpecifiers;
}
```

Maybe someone finds this useful.